# Strong Induction proof : $x_k = 1/2(x_{k+1}+x_{k-1})-1$ holds for all integers $k∈Z_{≥0}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-writing, induction, proof-explanation, alternative-proof

I have just started to learn how to do strong induction. I am struggling to fully understand how to properly do it though. I am trying to work on this exercise where I must prove $x_k = 1/2(x_{k+1}+x_{k-1})-1$ holds for all integers $k∈Z_{≥0}$. The terms are: $0,1,4,9,16...$ The term $x_1 = 1$ was given in the question but all the others were solved for.

I have so far defined a base case of $k=0$ and $k=1$ that holds true. I picked $0$ because it's the minimum value of $k$ and I picked $1$ because I thought I needed too, but I am not sure if it was necessary or why it would be necessary.

I then did the strong induction hypothesis where I state that $P(k)$ is true for all integers such that $0≤k≤n$, where $n∈Z$ such that $n≥1$. I picked $1$ because it's the largest base case value, but I am not sure if it is correct since I am unsure about the base case itself.

After this point, I am not sure how to really apply induction. I tried it many times but my proof doesn't look right.

I really need help on solving this, I am more comfortable with weak induction. I plan to use this solution as a reference for when I solve other problems, so I will be using it as an example to refer back too when I get stuck on tougher problems.

Thank you for any solutions or help provided,  I really appreciate it.

Comment: so $x_k = k^2$ is a given sequence ?

Comment: @ironX i guess it is, but it is not defined as such.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the use of $2$ previous index values (i.e., $x_k$ and $x_{k-1}$) in the sequence definition compared to the one with the highest index (i.e., $x_{k+1}$), when using [strong induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Complete_(strong)_induction), you correctly stated that you will need to define $2$ base cases (in general, the number of previous values in the definition determines the minimum number of base cases which are required). As your question statement implied (and [ironX](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/534898/ironx)'s question [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4051956/strong-induction-proof-x-k-1-2x-k1x-k-1-1-holds-for-all-integers/4051961#comment8369325_4051956) also stated), the hypothesis is that, with

$$x_k = \frac{x_{k+1} + x_{k-1}}{2} - 1 \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

and initial values of $x_0 = 0$ and $x_1 = 1$, we then have

$$x_k = k^2 \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

for all integers $k \ge 0$.

The $2$ initial, base values of $x_0$ and $x_1$ both satisfy \eqref{eq2A}. Next, the induction hypothesis is to assume \eqref{eq2A} holds for all non-negative integers $k \le n$ for some integer $n \ge 1$, as you already stated in your question text. To use this, first rearrange \eqref{eq1A} as

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
2x_k & = x_{k+1} + x_{k-1} - 2 \\
x_{k+1} & = 2x_k - x_{k-1} + 2
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

The induction hypothesis has $x_n = n^2$ and $x_{n-1} = (n-1)^2$, so using this and $k = n$ in \eqref{eq3A} gives

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
x_{n+1} & = 2x_{n} - x_{n-1} + 2 \\
& = 2(n^2) - (n-1)^2 + 2 \\
& = 2n^2 - (n^2 - 2n + 1) + 2 \\
& = 2n^2 - n^2 + 2n - 1 + 2 \\
& = n^2 + 2n + 1 \\
& = (n + 1)^2
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

This shows \eqref{eq2A} then also holds for $k = n + 1$, completing the induction step. Thus, this proves by strong induction that \eqref{eq2A} is true for all $k \ge 0$.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is to prove that if $x_k=k^2$ and $x_k=\frac{x_{k+1}+x_{k-1}}{2}-1$ then $x_{k+1}=(k+1)^2$, given $x_0=0, x_1=1$

$P(k): x_k=k^2\wedge x_k=\frac{x_{k+1}+x_{k-1}}{2}-1\Rightarrow x_{k+1}=(k+1)^2$

$P(k+1): x_{k+1}=(k+1)^2\wedge x_{k+1}=\frac{x_{k+2}+x_{k}}{2}-1\Rightarrow x_{k+2}=(k+2)^2$

You need to solve for $x_{k+2}$:

$(k+1)^2=\frac{x_{k+2}+k^2}{2}-1\Rightarrow ...x_{k+2}=(k+2)^2$

Therefore, $P(k)\Rightarrow P(k+1)$

Comment: You need  strong induction, not the ordinary mathematical induction.

Comment: If P(1) is true and $P(k)\Rightarrow P(k+1)$ then this is strong induction. I don’t need to prove that P(i) is true for all $i\le k$